# Rest API Design: Client to make N calls to a REST API "vs" middle tier to merge the data and have less API calls & bigger payload? (HTTP 1.1)

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

What's better

1) to have the client to make N calls to the Rest API, and keep every call as light as possible?

OR

2) to have a larger payload that's served to the client, and the payload is prepared by the middle tier?

I know that there is no one size fits all solution, and usually the business baggage plays the role. But let us forget about these for a moment, and let us imagine is a news website that's generic enough for this debate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If we forget every other consideration point and just focus on this specific angle as you suggested, then I would say, if you're front-end was going to make the 'N' calls to return the same data anyways (rather than paginate and only request the next page when required by the user), then making a single call is preferable in most, but **not all cases** (i.e. where the payloads are very large).

How large is very large? Among other factors, it depends on whether your consumers are in the same network vs. external network.

Factors **supporting** large payload:

1. Reduces network traffic and latency (i.e. back and forth involved with 'N' calls).
2. Consumers do not have to worry about merging and handling the data.
3. Usually easier to handle errors, as consumers will be dealing with a single response, rather than multiple calls that may have an impact on each other.

Factors **against** large payloads:

1. If the response time for the large payload is deemed slow, then you will
   keep your consumers waiting to view the results. With 'N'
   calls, you can potentially start displaying results whilst you're
   still loading the data. This may have an impact on user experience.
2. If the call fails mid-way, and you **do not** have fault-tolerance and continuity built-in, then you will have to replay the bigger payload, which forces the consumer to wait longer. This could be a significant factor if your payloads are very large.
3. Again, if you're payload is very large, then 'N' calls make sense as consumers can initiate multiple requests concurrently and receive the data quicker.

As I mentioned above, there are many factors to consider, and my response is probably too vanilla, but hopefully it gives you an idea as to how this can be approached.